# How to add commas to numbers

Tags: views

I have a text field. View select the text field. I entered three numeric values to the text field as 3321,33432 and 110343. In the view, I see the values without the commas. I like to see these numbers as 3,321, 33,432 and 110,343. Is there way I can rewrite the output using comma? Please provide some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What type of text field did you choose for your field? Regular text field?

If you want to be able to add comas. When you **add a new field to your content type** you need to **select INTEGER as your field type**, not text.

Then View's will detect that its an integer field (numbers only) and give you the comma option.

[image]

Comment: I allow max 6 digits number. When I selected Integer, I did not see the option to enter 6 as limit. Thats why I chose text field where I can enter 6 as limit. Do i have to create new integer field or I can just edit the text field type to integer? Also, how I can set the limit to 6 digits if the data type is integer?

Comment: @Drupol you have to create a new integer field, unfortunately Drupal doesn't allow to change field type once it's created. The Integer field does give you a maximum value option. So put 999999 as the max, which would be the equivalent of a 6 digit limit

Comment: @Drupol did this work for you?

Comment: It gives me empty space not the comma. Ex- If I enter 22343, it displays as 22 343. How can I display it as 22,343 instead?

Comment: That's because you need to change it from space to comma (see above picture) in your view's field.

Answer (score 1):

It is a PHP question, if the number is `$num` and you need no decimal point write

```
number_format($num,0,'.',',');
```

No matter what the field is, this code inserts thousands separator, you can use this in `Rewrite Results` textarea. more information in [PHP Number Format](http://php.net/number_format).

You can also install [currency](https://www.drupal.org/project/currency) module